# Find smallest largest number of odd and sum of even from a group of data

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, numbers

I need to find the smallest largest number of odd and sum of even from a group of data.

Data file example

```
2

1 2 4 5 6 7 8

2 5 6 7 4 2 1
```

The first line gives the number of lines that needs to be read (which is 2 in the example)

This is what I tried

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>


using namespace std;

int main()

{

    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    infile.open("input.txt");
    outfile.open("output.txt");

    int max = INT_MIN, min = INT_MAX, num_even = 0, num_odd = 0;
    int number, sum_even=0;
    int counter = 0;
    cout << "Test\n\n";
    cout << setw(15)<<left<<"Line";
    cout << setw(15) << left << "Smallest #";
    cout << setw(15) << left << "Largest #";
    cout << setw(15) << left << "# of Odds";
    cout << setw(15) << left << "Sum of evens\n\n";

    for (infile>>counter; counter>=1; counter--)
    {
        while (infile >> number)
        {

            if (number % 2 == 0) {
                num_even++;
                sum_even = sum_even + num_even;
            }

            else
                num_odd++;

            if (number > max)
                max = number;

            if (number < min)
                min = number;
        }
        cout << setw(15) << left << counter;
        cout << setw(15) << left << min;
        cout << setw(15) << left << max ;
        cout << setw(15) << left << num_odd;
        cout << setw(15) << left << sum_even << endl;
    }

    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It just reads the data as a complete set without it being line by line

Comment: What does "smallest largest number of odd" mean?

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: _"without it being line by line"_ Use `std::getline()` in 1st place and `std::istringstream` thereafter.

Comment: @R_Kapp I think user forgot to add commas in his sentence. "the smallest [number], largest [number], number of odd [numbers] and sum of even [numbers] from a group of data" is what I think user meant

Comment: your code doesn't compile because of 1) missing `climits` include 2) using `min` and `max` alongside `using namespace std;`. And you should check if your input file exists. Because your code works (after having fixed both points above)

Comment: Im sorry, yes. what I meant was - smallest [number], largest [number], number of odd [numbers] and sum of even [numbers] from a group of data. It runs fine but I want it to read the first number (2) and know that it has 2 lines of data to read. Then I want it to read those 2 lines of data and find the smallest [number], largest [number], number of odd [numbers] and sum of even [numbers] from it. The first line in the data file gives the number of lines it should read seperately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<climits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    infile.open("input.txt");
    outfile.open("output.txt");

    int counter = 0;

    cout << "Test\n\n";
    infile >> counter;
    string s;
    getline(infile, s, '\n' ); // get the '\n' after the first number
    for (int times = 1; times <= counter; times++)
    {
        // Initialize your variables
        int max = INT_MIN, min = INT_MAX, num_even = 0, num_odd = 0;
        int number, sum_even=0;

        // print the headers
        cout << setw(15) << left <<"Line";
        cout << setw(15) << left << "Smallest #";
        cout << setw(15) << left << "Largest #";
        cout << setw(15) << left << "# of Odds";
        cout << setw(15) << left << "Sum of evens\n";

        // get the next line, ending with '\n' (you'll have to check if your line endings depending on linux/windows)
        getline(infile, s, '\n' );
        // string stream
        istringstream is( s );

        // for each number in the string, make your validations
        while ( is >> number ) 
        {
            if (number % 2 == 0) {
                num_even++;
                // is this what are you after? couse you had 'num_even' here
                sum_even += number;
            }
            else
                num_odd++;

            if (number > max)
                max = number;

            if (number < min)
                min = number;
        }

        // print results
        cout << setw(15) << left << times;
        cout << setw(15) << left << min;
        cout << setw(15) << left << max ;
        cout << setw(15) << left << num_odd;
        cout << setw(15) << left << sum_even << endl;
    }

    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: Changed the code to omit the use of vectors**

Comment: Thanks! but is there anyway to do it without using vectors? By just using loops?

Comment: I haven't learnt vectors yet. I'm supposed to do it using just a simple loop

Comment: @user1642131, I have changed the code, take a look, and test if it works for you

Comment: there are erros at [is] and [is >> number] it says cannot convert from string to int

Comment: and, is uses undefined class

Comment: what c++ compiler version are you using?

here you can see the code using cin, instead on a file, you may use that page to test it

[link](http://ideone.com/e.js/OGw26k)

Comment: PS. I'm using c++14